# vectors. given a point and the distance between the point and origin, find equation of a line.

Tags: vector-spaces

> Find the equations of the lines which pass through the point $(1,2)$
>   and have perpendicular distance $1$ from the origin

For this question, I tried to use vectors and the dot product but I do not have enough equations to find out all the variables. I also tried to put them into $y=mx+C$ but I still do not know how to get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is useful to have the line defined via a normal:
$$
n \cdot (x - x_0) = 0
$$
where $n$ is a normal vector of the line, which for convenience we ask to be a unit vector and $x_0$ is an origin vector of the line (starts at the origin and ends on the line).

The vector $x^*$ on the line and closest to the origin is the one which has the same direction as $n$:
$$
x^* = \lVert x^* \rVert \, n = d \, n
$$
where $d$ is the perpendicular distance to the origin.

Together this gives
$$
d = n \cdot x_0
$$

[image: line]

Here $x_0 = (1,2)$ and we have $d = 1$:
$$
1 = n \cdot x_0 = n_x + 2 \, n_y
$$
This is the equation of a line. All norm vectors whose associated lines have unit distance to the origin lie on this line.

We add the unit vector condition:
$$
n_x^2 + n_y^2 = 1
$$
which is the unit circle.

Thus the feasible normal vectors are on the intersection of the above line and the unit circle, so we expect zero, one or two solutions.

[image: intersection problem]

$$
1 = n_x + 2 n_y = n_x \pm 2 \sqrt{1 - n_x^2} \Rightarrow \\
(1 - n_x)^2 = 4 (1 - n_x^2) \Rightarrow \\
1 - 2 \, n_x + n_x^2 = 4 - 4 \, n_x^2 \Rightarrow \\
5 \, n_x^2 - 2 \, n_x = 3 \Rightarrow \\
(n_x - 1/5)^2 = 3/5 + 1/25 \Rightarrow \\
n_x = 1/5 \pm 4/5 \in \{ 1, -3/5 \}
$$
So we get $(1, 0)$ and $(-3/5, \sqrt{1-9/25}) = (-3/5, 4/5)$ as normal vectors.

The equations of the lines are:
$$
0 = (1,0) \cdot ((x,y) - (1,2)) = x - 1 \iff x = 1
$$
and
$$
0 
= (-3/5, 4/5) \cdot ((x,y) - (1,2)) \\
= (-3/5)(x-1) + (4/5)(y-2) \\
= (-3/5) x + (4/5) y - 1  \iff \\
-3 x + 4 y = 5
$$

Answer (score 1):

Any line tangent to a circle passes through every point in the plane outside the circle twice - once with the 'front' of the line and once with the 'back' of the line.

In this case:

[image: circle]

One line is $x=2$, or in parametric form $t(1,0)+(1-t)(1,2)$.

If we let $a$ be the other point, and let  $ b_{12}=(1,2)$, then the parametric form of the line is $t(a_x,a_y)+(1-t)(1,2)$.

$a$ can be found as $\angle 0ab_{12}$ is a right-angle, $|oa|=1, |ab_{12}|=2$ and $|ob_{12}|=\sqrt{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If you want to calculate $\overrightarrow v$ out of $\overrightarrow v \bullet \overrightarrow w = 0$ it has an **infinite number of solutions**, because every vector that is perpendicular to $\overrightarrow w$ is a solution. So just pick a solution $(v_x,v_y)$ that suits the conditions.

Comment: Does this get you started? I just answered your problem with the vertices.